# F# problem with type inference in class methods with different order

Tags: f#, type-inference

This F# code compiles without error

```
type A() = 
    member private this.M1(tt: Task<'t>) = task {
        let! t = tt
        return t
    }

    member this.M4() = this.M2()
    member this.M2() = this.M1(Task.FromResult(1))
    member this.M3() = this.M1(Task.FromResult(1.0))
```

M4 calls M2 which is declared after. Now I move the private method at the end:

```
type A() = 
    member this.M4() = this.M2()
    member this.M2() = this.M1(Task.FromResult(1)) //FS0064
    member this.M3() = this.M1(Task.FromResult(1.0)) //FS0001

    member private this.M1(tt: Task<'t>) = task { //FS0064
        let! t = tt
        return t
    }
```

This code doesn't compile with the following errors:

> Warning    FS0064  This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type >annotations. The type variable 't has been constrained to be type 'int'.

> Error  FS0001  This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'float'

Please explain why this occurs and how to fix it (if possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# compiler is single-pass, including its type inference. It determines types based on their use as it goes through the program, from beginning to end, and it doesn't double back (except for `rec` bindings or modules).

In your particular example, as the compiler encounters method `M2`, it sees in its body that method `M1` is being called with a parameter of type `Task<int>`, so it infers that `M1 : Task<int> -> 'a` for some as of yet unknown `'a`

As it comes to the body of method `M3`, it sees `M1` being called with a parameter of type `Task<float>`, and this doesn't match the type information it has already determined, so it issues an error.

As it later comes to the definition of `M1` itself, it sees that the parameter is declared as generic. But the compiler already knows that the parameter must be `Task<int>`, so the generic parameter `'t` must always be equal to `int`, which is what it tells you: "*The type variable 't has been constrained to be type 'int'*". It issues a warning about it, because clearly, if you want it to be generic, but it's actually concrete, there must be something wrong somewhere.

This one-directional behavior is not a deficiency or oversight, it's very much on purpose. This allows the compiler to be simpler, faster, more efficient, and as a bonus, it often forces good program structure.

Comment: I think the key point is (Tomas says) "the members of a class are automatically treated as mutually recursive". As he says, this is a "subtle side-effect". IMO, this is a point where something should be done to improve. Why I find it acceptable with rec functions, I think it is less acceptable with class methods. I would prefer if methods are not implicitly recursive. Requiring to explicitly put a "rec" when a method needs to be recursive would be a better compromise. Mutually recursive could be done using the "and" keyword as happens with other constructs.